# Close MsgBox when selecting different cell

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to close a `MsgBox` when moving to a new cell. I know you can do it with a timer but that doesn't work for me. I have the following code:

```
If Target.Address = "$E$83" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("L3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E24").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("L24").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E25").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("L25").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E26").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("L26").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E27").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("L27").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E28").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("L28").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E23").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$84" Then
    MsgBox Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("M3").Value & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E24").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("M24").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E25").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("M25").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E26").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("M26").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E27").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("M27").Value & " Hours" _
        & vbNewLine & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E28").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("M28").Value & " Hours" _
            , , Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("E23").Value
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$84" Then
End If
```

So I want to be able to select `E83` and have the `MsgBox` come up, then click `E84` and have the new `MsgBox` come up, without having to close the first `MsgBox`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a `MsgBox` - the user would HAVE TO click it.

Instead, make a UserForm that looks like a message box, and use that instead...

```
frmMsgBox.txtMessage = Worksheets("Budget Hours").Range("M3").Value
frmMsgBox.Show vbModeless
```

This assumes the name of the UserForm to be `frmMsgBox` and a TextBox on the form called `txtMessage`.

Build your text any way you want (probably best to set it to a variable first) and then set the text equal to that.